# Is it possible to to create entity classes from two databases that have tables with the same names?

Tags: hibernate, netbeans

The following question refers to Netbeans 7.2, but I expect it also applies to 7.1, 7.0, 6.8 and 6.9.

I am trying to map entities classes from two different databases DB1 and DB2, both of which contain a table with the same name, TB. The fields in DB1.TB and DB2.TB are totally different.

I'm generating entities for the two databases and dropping the classes into separate packages (lets say "entities.db1" for DB1 and "entities.db2" for DB2).

The problem is that when I generate entities for the second database, the TB table already exists, and so only allows me to either UPDATE or RECREATE. Recreating deletes the other TB entity, and updating creates a hot mess.

I've tried creating separate persistence units, but that didn't seem to make any difference (and there is no way of selecting the PU in the Entity Classes from Database wizard).

I don't really want to have to have classes named Db1Tb and Db2Tb, though it's looking like I don't have a choice. My question is, am I doing something wrong? Is there another way to create entity classes using Netbeans where two tables have the same name?

Comment: Would it be a better idea to generate all the classes in two separate EJB Module projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that separation is the key... I've created three projects:

- myEntities: Entity classes from Database (disabled creation of a Persistence Unit)
- myEJBs: Session Beans for Entity classes and Local interfaces (the PU goes here)
- myEJBRemotes: Remote interfaces (created by the Session Beans wizard)

If only a single web application was referring to these beans I could have packaged them all up and deployed them together. However, since I intend to create several independently-deployed web applications, adding the EJBs as dependencies to each module creates a problem: at deployment Glassfish complains that an EJB with that name has already been deployed.

Once again, separation was the solution... My first idea was to deploy the EJB module and then add the Entity and Remote modules as dependencies to my web applications. This didn't quite work - the EJB module had no reference to the Entity classes (when deploying an EJB, its dependencies are not included in the package sent to the application server).

Creating *another* project, this time one that packaged the ejb modules and associated jars (Entities and Remotes) together as an EAR, finally did the trick. This EAR can be deployed stand-alone on Glassfish, and then web applications only need to add dependencies on the Entity and Remote jars...

Tips:

1. about the maven-ear-plugin: add `<defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>` to the configuration otherwise the libs get put in the root of the ear and glassfish starts throwing NoClassDef exceptions.
2. about the web applications: if you are deploying your web apps in separate EARs and you are, for example, trying to use some custom queries you *can't* "borrow" the EntityManager from the EJB's as you could if everything was bundled together (at least, not as far as I know). You need to create a new persistence unit though you can share several units in a single `persistence.xml` file, and you can of course reuse the entities you created for the EJB.
3. about the persistence unit(s): because the persistence unit is not in the same project as the entities, make sure you set `<exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>` and include all the entity classes that the PU represents. This is true for the PU in both the EJB module *and* the web application.

I'm sure this isn't the only way to do this, and it's probably (more than likely) not the best way either. I'd happily listen to anyone offering a better way...